# Formatting a single row as CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating a script to convert a whole lot of data into CSV format. It runs on Google AppEngine using the mapreduce API, which is only relevant in that it means each row of data is formatted and output separately, in a callback function.

I want to take advantage of the logic that already exists in the `csv` module to convert my data into the correct format, but because the CSV writer expects a file-like object, I'm having to instantiate a `StringIO` for each row, write the row to the object, then return the content of the object, each time.

This seems silly, and I'm wondering if there is any way to access the internal CSV formatting logic of the `csv` module without the writing part.

Comment: Does the `tempfile` module help?  You can give a file handle which is not really visible in the OS

Comment: @wim Thanks, but not really. I'd still need a separate one for each row, even if it weren't for the fact that there's no access to the filesystem on AppEngine.

Comment: Never got to have a look to mapreduce, so I'm not sure about the constraints, in particular when it comes to the callback execution environment. Does your program (the one providing the callback) run during the whole call to mapreduce? Ie. can you keep the global state, or do you really need to reinstantiate things like the `StringIO` each time? (Not suggesting to keep global objects, mind you, it's just I'd like to know the environment)

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes it distributes the task to multiple independent shards, so there's no global state.

Comment: @DanielRoseman was just reading about it in mapreduce's doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The csv module wraps the _csv module, which is written in C.  You could grab the source for it and modify it to not require the file-like object, but poking around in the module, I don't see any clear way to do it without recompiling.

Comment: (and here App Engine becomes extremely relevant, since you can't deploy re-compiled C extensions)

Answer (score 3):

One option could be having your own "file-like" object. Actually, `cvs.writer` requires for the object only to have a `write` method, so:

```
class PseudoFile(object):
    def write(self, string):
        # Do whatever with your string

csv.writer(PseudoFile()).writerow(row)
```

You're skipping a couple steps in there, but maybe it's just what you want.