# Protect commas on consecutive string.join() and string.split()

Tags: python

Suppose the following code (notice the commas inside the strings):

```
>>> a = ['1',",2","3,"]
```

I need to concatenate the values into a single string. Naive example:

```
>>> b = ",".join(a)
>>> b
'1,,2,3,'
```

And later I need to split the resulting object again:

```
>>> b.split(',')
['1', '', '2', '3', '']
```

However, the result I am looking for is the *original* list:

```
['1', ',2', '3,']
```

What's the simplest way to protect the commas in this process? The best solution I came up with looks rather ugly.

Note: the comma is just an example. The strings can contain any character. And I can choose other characters as separators.

Comment: How would you know the original is `['1',  ',2',  '3,']` instead of `['1,',  '2',  '3,']` ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is replace , in original with some other character or use some other delimiter to separate values.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the joined string? The `csv` module will deal perfectly well with elements containing commas, but you won't see strings like "1,,2,3," because it's completely impossible to know where the commas are separators vs. parts of the data.

Comment: you can use `\x00` or `&&&&` as a delimiter =)

Comment: @KennyTM precisely, that's the issue! :)

Comment: @Wooble I guess that means the csv module is not an option in this case :\

Comment: @newtover However unlikely, I can't guarantee there won't be any &&&& in the input. I have to check better about \x00. It might be an option.

Comment: What @KennyTM and @Wooble are meaning, is that there's NO way to know if `'1,,2,3'` corresponds to `['1,', '2', '3']` or to `['1', ',2', '3']`. You really need to join with something different than `','`.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia: if '1,",2","3,"' is an acceptable representation in your string, then the csv module is perfectly fine. (it can also be used with a customized separator and quote character, depending on your needs)

Comment: If you're not worried about how the strings print, the ASCII record separator character (hex 1E) may also be a good choice; it's very underused but this is exactly the sort of thing it exists for.

Comment: @woobie, `1e` is a very nice suggestion! Thank you! (though I am not the OP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The strings can contain any character.

If no matter what you use as a delimiter, there is a chance that the item itself contains the delimiter character, then use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv):

```
import csv

class PseudoFile(object):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/8712426/190597
    def write(self, string):
        return string
writer = csv.writer(PseudoFile())
```

This concatenates the items in `a` using commas:

```
a = ['1',",2","3,"]
line = writer.writerow(a)
print(line)
# 1,",2","3,"
```

This recovers `a` from `line`:

```
print(next(csv.reader([line])))
# ['1', ',2', '3,']
```

Comment: No need for `io.BytesIO`, `csv.reader` can take any iterable so you can just give it `[line]`.

Comment: I've gone this route. The code would be slightly cleaner using the JSON module instead, as suggested by @Gandaro, but it would make it more difficult to understand IMHO (it's a non-Web project, using no Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use comas to separate the items?  Else you could also use another symbol that is not used in the items of the list.

```
In [1]: '|'.join(['1', ',2', '3,']).split('|')
Out[1]: ['1', ',2', '3,']
```

Edit: The string may apparently contain *any* character.  Is it an option to use the `json` module?  You could just dump and load the list.

```
In [3]: json.dumps(['1', ',2', '3,'])
Out[3]: '["1", ",2", "3,"]'

In [4]: json.loads('["1", ",2", "3,"]')
Out[4]: [u'1', u',2', u'3,']
```

Edit #2: If you may not use it, you could use `str.encode('string-encode')` to escape the characters in your string and then enclose the encoded version into single quotes and separate those with comas:

```
In [10]: print "'example'".encode('string-escape')
\'example\' #' (have to close the opened string for stackoverflow

In [11]: print r"\'example\'".decode('string-escape')
'example'
```

Edit #3: Running example of `str.encode('string-encode')`:

```
import re

def list_to_str(list):
    return ','.join("'{}'".format(s.encode('string-escape')) for s in list)

def str_to_list(str):
    return re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ['1', ',2', '3,']
    b = list_to_str(a)
    print 'It is {} that this works.'.format(str_to_list(b) == a)
```

Comment: Yes, the strings can contain any character. I will try to make it clearer in the question.

Comment: Using encode('string-escape') ´Produce[s] a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code´. It doesn't really protect the commas, right?

Comment: Using the json module looks lile good approach, thanks. But in that case the csv module is more in-line with what I'm trying to do

Comment: Well, you can then use a regular expression or so to "unpack" the data. (for example, `re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", "'1',',2','3,'")` returns `['1', ',2', '3,']`)

Answer (score 1):

When you are serializing a list to a String, then you need to choose as a separator a character that doesn't appear in the list items. Can't you just replace the comma with another character?

```
b = ";".join(a)
b.split(';')
```

Comment: The coma is just an example... The strings can also contain semicolons. I've tried making this cleared in the question.

Comment: Then do find a character ('\t' for example) that the strings do not contain.

Answer (score 1):

Does the delimiter need to be only a single character?  If not then you can use a delimiter made up of a sequence of characters that definitley wont appear in your string, like |#| or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the comma and probably also escape the escape sequence. Here's one way:

```
>>> a = ['1',",2","3,"]
>>> b = ','.join(s.replace('%', '%%').replace(',', '%2c') for s in a)
>>> [s.replace('%2c', ',').replace('%%', '%') for s in b.split(',')]
['1', ',2', '3,']
>>> b
'1,%2c2,3%2c'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would join and split using another character than `","`, e.g. `";"`:

```
>>> b = ";".join(a)
>>> b.split(';')
['1', ',2', '3,']
```